# Add span for exist values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<table>
    <tr><td has="one">test</td><td has="three">test</td></tr>
    <tr><td has="two">test</td><td has="four">test</td></tr>
</table>

table td {
   border: solid 1px green;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

I would like receive:

```
<table>
    <tr><td has="one"><span class="one">test</span></td><td has="one"><span class="one">test</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td has="one"><span class="one">test</span></td><td has="one"><span class="one">test</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Attribute has == class in new span.

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/LgE3q/

I must use jQuery. Is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$('table [has]').each(function() {
    $(this).wrapInner($('<span />').addClass($(this).attr('has')));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LgE3q/4/